# How to take a picture in a browser and upload it with http protocol?

Tags: javascript, photo, capture, hololens

I want to capture a photo from the camera and upload it to the server. My target environments are EDGE browser for Hololens and PC browsers (At least latest versions of Chrome or Firefox).

I have tried using HTML5 `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">` However both in the Hololens Edge and PC Chrome the capture attribute is ignored.( This works as it should in Chrome for Android )

I have tried `getUserMedia`.

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
      function(stream) {
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         video.srcObject = stream;
         video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
           video.play();
         };
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

and then: to get a picture from the video playing.

But `getUserMedia` is a powerful feature and I need secure origin. It plays using `localhost`, but not when i use `localIP` instead.
According to [chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)

> “Secure origins” are origins that match at least one of the following
>   (scheme, host, port) patterns:
>
> (https, *, *)
>
> (wss, *, *)
>
> (*,localhost, *)
>
> (*, 127/8, *)
>
> (*, ::1/128, *)
>
> (file, *, —)
>
> (chrome-extension, *, —)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a localhost with a "[self-signed SSL certificate](https://www.google.com/search?ei=aAb9W8isKoHUwQLm6omQBg&q=self-signed%20certificate%20https&oq=self-signed%20certificate%20https&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203j0i30l2j0i5i30l7.8915.10151..11066...0.0..0.74.422.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i7i30j0i7i30i19j0i7i5i30i19.1dZhIPt6DnE)" (google search link) so you have a https server.

This is ok for your testing environment but of course not for production.

So if this is set up and works, to capture a photo, you need to paint your video on to a `canvas`, so you have get the image you need.

Comment: I wanted to do it in production using http, because the video does play in localhost.

Comment: That is right. It works with `localhost`, and that is for testing only. But if you open the browser with your local ip (whatever that is, for example `http://192.168.2.17`) it will not run.  As you wrote yourself in your post `getUserMedia` needs https. 
Besides that, in 2018 everything should run in a secure environment anyway.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I know it does not work if I use my ip, as i have mentioned what is considered a "secure origin". What I am asking, is about another way to take a picture.